# Faster solution for extracting array of word-vectors from text string with R

Tags: r, string, performance, for-loop, full-text-search

I am looping over text to find and count specific words from various dictionaries. I use two FOR loops which are extremely slow and takes days to complete. Reproducible code below:

```
library(stringr)

#Sample data
tweets=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),text=c("This is a tweet that contains word1",
                                     "And here you can find word1 and word2 word2",
                                     "And here is only one word3 and one word3a"))

words=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),word=c("word1","word2","word3"))

for(i in 1:nrow(tweets)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(words)){
    term = paste("\\<",words[j,2],"\\>", sep="")
    if (str_count(tweets[i,2], term) != 0) {
     tmp <- data.frame(id=tweets[i,1],termfound=words[j,2],count=str_count(tweets[i,2], term), row.names=NULL)
     message("ID ",tweets[i,1]," - Word '",words[j,2],"' found ",str_count(tweets[i,2], term)," times")
     #sqlSave(myconn, tmp, "DataTable", append=T, rownames=F)
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTES:**
I have ~1M lines of text and ~25,000 words I am counting.
The Message line is just for debugging.
The final values are written to SQL - line commented out as it is not reproducible.

Any way to improve on this? I was thinking an APPLY function???

Cheers
B

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do here, but you might find the [`tm`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) package useful, it has many functions for this kind of text mining. The [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf) demonstrates how to use most of them. It uses document term matrices as sparse matrices which are quite fast to work with.

Comment: Sounds like you need a little `stringi` in your life

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I use the TM package extensively, but it has its limitations. I do use dtm and tdm and all of that. Don't worry too much about what I am trying to do, I'm just after faster code for this specific example code, there are more to it which I have left out on purpose.

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven, I am just wondering how that is going to make it faster? I had a quick look and it seems you have the same str_count type functions? or am I missing the plot completely?

Comment: @RUser - the names are similar yes, but they are *completely* different.  `stringi` is written in C and virtually everything is vectorized, making it great for nesting and passing to other package functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Observation:  your code is counting each word three times.  Once in the IF statement, once in the tmp assignment and once in the debug message.  Reducing the number of calls to the string counting function will definitely improve the efficiency of your code.

As mentioned above, the stringi package offers a faster set of string functions.

The following vectorized code will generate a 2-d matrix with the results you want which can
then be transformed into the format needed for your database.

```
require(stringi)
tweets=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),text=c("This is a tweet that contains word1",
                                     "And here you can find word1 and word2 word2",
                                     "And here is only one word3 and one word3a"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
words=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),word=c("word1","word2","word3"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
pat <- paste("\\b",words$word,"\\b", sep="")
sd <- function(text) { stri_count(text, regex=pat) }
results <- sapply(tweets$text, sd, USE.NAMES=F)
colnames(results) <- words$word
rownames(results) <- paste("ID", tweets$id)
results
```

Which produces the following output:

```
##      word1 word2 word3
## ID 1     1     1     0
## ID 2     0     2     0
## ID 3     0     0     1
```

Comment: Great answer! I think it could be slightly improved. For @RUser with millions texts and thousands words a little bit faster will be *apply over words, not texts. So corresponding lines of text will looks like: text <- tweets$text
sd <- function(word) { stri_count(str = text, regex=word) }
results <- t(vapply(pat, sd, FUN.VALUE=numeric(length(text)),USE.NAMES=F))

Comment: @GregoryDemin - I don't think you'll want to transpose a million lines of text

Comment: @RichardScriven It is integer matrix, not text. And transpose is not very hard operation - I suppose it only changes indexes of matrix and doesn't move data. After all there is no needs to transpose - we will have the same result but with another indexing. But there is another problem. I try to benchmark different approaches and on my machine with 8 Gb of memory it is rather difficult to work with matrix of 1e10 elements in general. So I think in any case it will be better to process data by chunks and put results in the database (as in commented line in topic starter's code).

Answer (score 5):

**Update :** You could also try `stringi` within a `data.table`.

```
library(data.table); library(stringi)

## convert tweets to  data table and set key on 'id' column 
dtweets <- as.data.table(tweets)
setkey(dtweets, id)

## convert words to data.table and set up the regex
dtw <- as.data.table(words)
dtw[,term := stri_c("\\b", word, "\\b")]

## run stri_count_regex by each id 
dtn <- dt[dtw, stri_count_regex(text, term), by = key(dt)]
#    id V1
# 1:  1  1
# 2:  1  0
# 3:  1  0
# 4:  2  1
# 5:  2  2
# 6:  2  0
# 7:  3  0
# 8:  3  0
# 9:  3  1 

## melt the rows to columns
melted <- melt(dtn, id = 1L, measure = 2L)
dcast(melted, id ~ value, sum)
#   id 0 1 2
# 1  1 0 1 0
# 2  2 0 1 2
# 3  3 0 1 0
```

---

**Original answer**

Here's another method that takes the logical matches only, then calculates the result from those values.  I had to use `\\b` for the word boundary in `term`.

```
library(stringi)

term <- stri_c("\\b", words$word, "\\b")

out <- vapply(seq_along(tweets$text), function(i) {
        a <- stri_detect_regex(tweets$text[i], term)
        a[a] <- cumsum(a[a != 0])
        a
    }, integer(nrow(tweets)))

cbind(tweets[1], `colnames<-`(out, words$word))
#   id word1 word2 word3
# 1  1     1     1     0
# 2  2     0     2     0
# 3  3     0     0     1
```

Comment: Term is used in the str_count function. It is a regex term to define standalone words only.

Answer (score 3):

I had pretty much the same idea about this problem as Daddy the Runner:

```
term = paste("\\<",words$word,"\\>", sep="") # create a regex for every word
# [1] "\\<word1\\>" "\\<word2\\>" "\\<word3\\>"

m <- sapply(tweets$text,function(tweet) str_count(tweet,term)) # find a number of occurences of every word in every tweet
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    0
# [2,]    0    2    0
# [3,]    0    0    1



library(reshape)
df <- melt(m) # convert the result into the data frame format
#   X1 X2 value
# 1  1  1     1
# 2  2  1     0
# 3  3  1     0
# 4  1  2     1
# 5  2  2     2
# 6  3  2     0
# 7  1  3     0
# 8  2  3     0
# 9  3  3     1

colnames(df) <- c('id.tweet','id.word','count')

tmp <- with(df,data.frame(id=id.tweet,termfound=words$word[id.word],count=count)) # create a data frame similar to the one in the example
# id termfound count
# 1  1     word1     1
# 2  2     word1     0
# 3  3     word1     0
# 4  1     word2     1
# 5  2     word2     2
# 6  3     word2     0
# 7  1     word3     0
# 8  2     word3     0
# 9  3     word3     1
```

Comment: Marat, I like your solution. The only issue I have at the moment is preserving the original ID. My sample data has ID's of 1,2,3 for the sake of convenience, but my real data is not sequential.

Comment: Then, you should just replace `id=id.tweet` by `id=tweets$id[id.tweet]`, i.e. `tmp <- with(df,data.frame(id=tweets$id[id.tweet],termfound=words$word[id.word],count=count))`